# Adding a mail server to existing network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, firewall, ssl

I'm adding a `VM mailer` and would like support on the new layout on my network.

I currently have a `firewall` that forwards connections to a `VM nginx` that deals with HTTP/HTTPS requests, forwarding to respective internal servers (`wordpress`, `IIS`).

I'm not sure where to place this new `VM mailer`. My initial ideia was to place it behind existing `VM nginx`, but then I wondered if I should place `VM mailer` directly connected to the `firewall`.

If I place behind `VM nginx` then I would have to add a `listen` server block to each additional ports (25, 587 and 80 for `mailer.example.com`) and deal with the internet noise on port 25. I wonder if this would decrease somehow my system performance, since this route is mainly for my `IIS` applications.

If I place directly into the `firewall`, I'm not shure how I could issue the SSL certificate (`LetsEncrypt`).

What's the suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

Most mail servers and web servers have a way to specify certs.

For example, you can make a cert for *.mydomain.com

Then you just use the same cert for all your servers.

If your cert isn't of the wildcard type then you will need individual certs for the domain and mail.mydomain.com or whatever you call it.

If your using Linux, I hope your running fail2ban to block random internet people.

It should be connected to the firewall, otherwise you would have to forward the traffic from the original VM to this VM.

That would cause an addition work load(forwarding packets) on the 1st VM for no apparent reason.